# how retrieve data from a table and convert id to names?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I want to show the name of a user and who is his best friend from the same table.
However, the problem is that I want to show the name of the best friend not his ID.
How can I solve this? I am saving `id` in `bestFriend` column.

table structure:

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | name    | bestFriend |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply self-join the table

```
SELECT u.name AS user_name, f.name AS friend_name
FROM table AS u
INNER JOIN table AS f
    ON u.bestFriend = f.id
WHERE u.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name name, b.name bestFriend
FROM mytable a, mytable b
WHERE a.bestFriend = b.id
AND a.id = <your_id>
```

[click here for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2384d/1)